# function with moving average on matlab

Tags: functions, matlab

Do a function that maintains moving average, the function gives the average of all the numbers that have been put in the function.

does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

**Moving** average of `n` points: use [`conv`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/conv.html):

```
data = [1 2 4 6 8 11 5];
n = 3;
result = conv(data, repmat(1/n, [1 n]), 'valid');
```

**Cumulative** average from the beginning to current position: use [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
result = cumsum(data)./(1:numel(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

If `list` is an array of numbers of the form `[a,b,c,...,z]` then we can simply take

```
average = sum(list)/length(list)
```

If you prefer not to have numbers entered as an array, you can do this:

```
function y = average(varargin)

    list = cell2mat(varargin);
    y = sum(list)/length(list);
```